# Can not answer phone after enabling Google Voice

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, google-voice, auto-answer

I Have a Sprint Google Nexus S.  Was working fine.  Enabled Google Voice - set up my account, options, etc.   All incoming calls require pressing "1" to answer.   This worked for a while.  Now, when a call comes in, I am pressing "1", but the call does not answer - it goes to voice mail.   Ideas?

ler

Answer (score 1):

If you have not yet rebooted your device since this problem started, do that first, then try the following if that still doesn't correct the issue.

Log in to the [Google Voice site](http://voice.google.com) and go to Settings -> Calls and turn off Call Screening.

Now see if a call will go through, you wont have to press "1" because you are no longer screening. If you do want call screening, Try to now turn the call screening back on.